# Facebook Oauth prompt does not ask for all the scopes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I am building a Facebook app that posts to user's pages on their behalf. This is the Oauth request that I am making to Facebook -

[https://www.facebook.com/v7.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=https://app.fuzen.io/api/v1/facebookconnect&state=fluxm&response_type=code&scopes[]=pages_manage_posts&scopes[]=pages_read_engagement&scopes[]=pages_read_user_content](https://www.facebook.com/v7.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=https://app.fuzen.io/api/v1/facebookconnect&state=fluxm&response_type=code&scopes%5B%5D=pages_manage_posts&scopes%5B%5D=pages_read_engagement&scopes%5B%5D=pages_read_user_content)

As per facebook's documentation, the scopes in this request can only be approved by test users. But when I log in with Facebook test user account to approve these scopes, I only see basic scopes - name & profile picture, instead of - pages_manage_posts etc.

[image: Facebook Oauth prompt]

If the test user approves this request only basic permissions are granted to get name & profile picture. Is the oauth request not correctly structured or do I need to change something in the app settings? The app is currently in development mode.

Comment: `scopes[]=` is just wrong. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#login: _“`scope`. A comma or space separated list of Permissions to request from the person using your app.”_

Comment: please edit and put the image in the question instead of link !

Comment: @AlexisBenichoux this being my very first question on the platform, I don't yet have permission to add images :)